# Angular2 Eclipse can not resolve node module

Tags: javascript, eclipse, angular

I was trying to get a angular2 quick start working in eclipse (not an official one I think, it's from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_-CD_5YhJTA). So I used the "AngularJS Eclipse 1.2.0" plugin for eclipse.

All is working great after I added 
 to my boot.ts because Angular was throwing several errors that it can not find "promise".

The only problem I was not able to solve, is that in my index.html several script tags (e.g. ) are marked red with an error message (e.g. "Undefined JavaScript file ("./node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"))."

Someone an idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: I suggest you that you install https://github.com/angelozerr/angular2-eclipse if you wish to develop Angular2

Comment: Hi @Angelo, 
as I mentioned above the plugin is already installed, not via github but via eclipse marketplace.

Comment: "Undefined JavaScript file" is not managed with typescript.java. Perhaps you have installed Eclipse WTP WebResources? For your promise pb, I suggest you that you create an issue to typescript.java and share your project.